# how to find that there is a "Promoted to front page" node and load it in page.tpl.php?

Tags: nodes

because front page has no `arg(1)` (node id)  I cannot load promoted node[s] in page.tpl.php .
all I want to do is print something in one part of front page if a specific content type node in about to load in node.tpl.php.
I search it alot but find no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean a custom function?

I did a lot of this for a current project where we needed short little lists of nodes with different criterion all over.  I found Views bulky and overkill in some places, so I added small functions to template.php.  They're really just simple SQL SELECT statements.

For example:

```
function home_channel_list($title, $tids, $limit){

    $query = "SELECT t1.nid, MAX(t1.vid), t1.title, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.field_pubdate_value) AS pubdate
                FROM {node} t1
                    JOIN field_revision_field_pubdate t2 ON t1.nid = t2.entity_id AND t1.vid = t2.revision_id
                    JOIN field_revision_field_channel t3 ON t1.nid = t3.entity_id AND t1.vid = t3.revision_id
                WHERE t3.field_channel_tid IN(".$tids.")
                    GROUP BY t1.nid ORDER BY pubdate DESC LIMIT ".$limit."";

        $result = db_query($query); 

        // Container div and title
        print '<div class="home-channel-block"><h2>'.$title.'</h2>';

        // Article list
        foreach ($result as $record) {
            $mypubdate = format_date($record->pubdate, 'custom', 'F j, Y, g:iA');
            print '<div class="home-channel-title"><a href="?q=node/'.$record->nid.'">'.$record->title.'</a></div>';
            print '<div class="home-channel-pubdate pubdate">'.$mypubdate.'</div>';         
        }

        // Clear and close the container div
        print '<div class="myclear"></div></div>';
}
```

Comment: yes I think sql solution in the only option in my specific needs, thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand - but I would create a block either from a view or with a custom function that pulls a list of articles where node_revision.promote = 1. Then just have it display on the front page only.

Comment: what I want to achieve is just cheking in page.tpl.php file that a specific content type node will be later load in node.tpl.php or not , either by user viewing node/nid or front page (in front page case by promoting node[s] of that specific content type). in former case it is easy like bellow:

Comment: `
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
 $node = node_load(array('nid' => arg(1)));
 if (($node->type == 'slideshow') {
  //do some stuff
 }
}
`
I can check that current page is front or not but problem is that I am not sure promoted node will be that specific content type that I need.
your second suggestion seems interesting , can you explain how I implement it? tnx.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `node_page_default()` in `modules/node/node.module` and it's output, but I think its better to use another `page.tpl.php` for those content type via suggesting new .tpl files to theme layer via this function in `template.php`:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['node'])) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $variables['node']->type;
  }
}
```

so you can have `page--node--news.tpl.php` for news content type ...